# Grouped ListView with Checkbox in Header

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, checkbox, grouping

I have a ListView bound to some data, and it's grouped and sorted. I added a checkbox to to the grouping header like so:

```
            <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Expander IsExpanded="True" BorderBrush="#FFA4B97F" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                            <DockPanel>
                                                <CheckBox>
                                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                                                        <TextBlock Text=" ("/>
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}"/>
                                                        <TextBlock Text=" Items)"/>
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </CheckBox>
                                            </DockPanel>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <Expander.Content>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander.Content>
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
```

Now I only care and need a way to loop through the grouped items that have the header checked, what's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly its not as straightforward as it needs to be,

Remember that a group's header `CheckBox` has a  `DataContext` which is a special kind of object called `GroupItem`. In this `GroupItem` there is `Name` property which is the value that the group represents i.e. the common value on the basis of which grouping has occurred.

Many people confuse this with the group description property e.g. assuming you have added a `GroupDescription` with property `EmployeeStatus` in your `CollectionView` of employees, then `GroupItem.Name` is NOT `EmployeeStatus` but it is in fact the value on which group was created such as `Present`, `Absent`, `OnLeave` etc.

Having this knowledge, lets try to achieve what you seek ...

1. We name the header checkbox, say "HeaderCheckBox"

   ```
   <CheckBox x:Name="HeaderCheckBox" ...>
   ```
2. We handle `Button.Click` (a bubbling attached event) at the ListView level.

   ```
   <ListView Button.Click="HandleCheckBoxClick" ...>
   ```
3. In the handler `HandleButtonClick` we do the following code....

   ```
   private void HandleCheckBoxClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       var checkBox = e.OriginalSource as CheckBox;
       if (checkBox != null && checkBox.Name == "HeaderCheckBox")
       {
           var groupItem = checkBox.DataContext as GroupItem;

           //// Assuming MyItem is the item level class and MyGroupedProperty 
           //// is the grouped property that you have added to the grouped
           //// description in your CollectionView.
           foreach (MyItem item in groupItem.Items)
           {
                //// Place your code for the items under that particular group.
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Sadly this is the only way to achieve what you seek. If you are using MVVM, then the entire code will have to be done through an attached behavior.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yes thank you, I can turn that into a working solution. I was really however just looking for a way to get a list of groups with the header checkbox checked after the list had been populated. Instead however using your code I can just have an invisible column with a checkbox as a member of the class that's being displayed and just control the checkboxes depending on which group has been checked and then it's easy to find which items are checked and which are not. Thank you again!

Comment: You can get all groups, I think `ListView` exposes `Items` property... I guess that should have the individual groups.... This is a rookie guess and it may not win you the Derby. :-)

Comment: In .NET 4 it is not GroupItem but CollectionViewGroup